# How to add java libraries in netbeans 12

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to import java libraries in Netbeans. For older versions, I found on the internet that the solution was to simply go to the project properties and then select libraries. However, in netbeans 12 I don't have an option like this. My project properties look like this:

[image]

How do I import libraries for this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I understand much to it, but a solution for me was to build the project with Ant instead of Maven. Then the libraries appear in the properties of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I try to get an library importing from code.. for example in yout "main" class.

for example u can write
*Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("test.mdb"));*

Later you can try import manually from setting project.

regards!!